# Access contract method via web3

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js

I have a following simple contract that stores file details:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract FileDetail {
    uint fileSize;
    string fileName;
    string fileType;

 function set(uint fileS,string fileN, string fileT) {
        fileSize = fileS;
        fileName = fileN;
        fileType = fileT;
    }
}
```

How do I access the set method from web3 js and pass the needed parameters ?

Answer (score 1):

After deploying your contract you can call set function as follow :

```
var MContract = web3.eth.contract(“your contract’s ABI”);
var contractInstance= MContract.at(“contract address”);
var fileS=...;
var fileN=...;
var fileT=...;
contractInstance.set(fileS,fileN,fileT,{from: eth.accounts[0],  gas: 200000}, function(error, result){...});
```

read more here : https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API

Answer (score 1):

This code works for a local testrpc. For mainnet, replace the httpProvider.

```
var Web3 = require(‘web3’);
var web3 = new Web3();
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider(“http://localhost:8545"));

var abiFileContract = web3.eth.contract(PASTE ABI HERE!);
var fileContract = abiFileContract.at('PASTE CONTRACT ADDRESS HERE');

fileContract.set(12, ‘Stephen Hawkings’, ‘Stephen Hawkings’);
```